# Python 3 urllib encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, lxml

I have a piece of code in Python 3 that retrieves information from a website :

```
webpage = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bdm.insee.fr/bdm2/index.action')
webpage = webpage.read()
webpage = webpage.decode("ISO-8859-1")
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(webpage,parser)
for liste in tree.iterfind(".//ul"):
   print(etree.tostring(liste, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

I don't understand why some characters are rightly encoded while others aren't. Here is a portion of the output :

```
<ul class="liens"><li><a href="http://www.insee.fr/fr/publications-et-services/default.asp?page=rediffusion/rediffusion-abon-bdm.htm">Souscription</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="lienstransversauxbas"><li class="premier" id="navigation-lettre">&#13;
<a href="http://www.insee.fr/fr/publications-et-services/default.asp?page=abonnements/liste-abonnements.htm" title="Lire la lettre d'information">Lettre d'information</a>&#13;
</li>&#13;
<li id="navigation-plan">&#13;
<a accesskey="3" href="http://www.insee.fr/fr/publications-et-services/services/plan-du-site.asp" title="Plan du site">Plan du site</a>&#13;
</li>&#13;
<li id="navigation-boutique">&#13;
<a href="http://www.webcommerce.insee.fr/index.php" title="Acc&#233;der &#224; la boutique en ligne">Acheter les publications</a>&#13;
</li>&#13;
<li id="navigation-credits">&#13;
<a accesskey="8" href="http://www.insee.fr/fr/publications-et-services/default.asp?page=copyright.htm" title="Copyright Insee">Mentions l&#233;gales et cr&#233;dits</a>&#13;
</li>&#13;
</ul>
```

What are those &#13?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Don't use `urllib`.. I suggest `requests` - Its for the modern web!

Comment: Not that that's bad advice, but it has absolutely nothing to do with the behavior he's seeing whatsoever.

Comment: It would be better if I could stick with standard packages but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Those are carriage returns.  I suspect `etree` is explicitly including them so that the whitespace will be preserved, much like using `&nbsp;` to preserve space.  That's a guess, though; I don't see `&#13;` in the original source, so I'm not clear why `etree`'s going out of its way to preserve it.

Comment: So you're saying that it's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: I think so, but I'm not completely familiar with what `etree`'s intended operation is here.  In other words: I know what it is (I answered that), and it's not wrong for it to be they *per se*, but it's completely unnecessary and doesn't contribute anything.